# Jenkins pipeline: how to access custom globals from groovy scripts in vars dir?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am able to declare a class instance as global like this :

```
gitUtils = new GitUtils()

pipeline {
  ...
  echo "hello: " + gitUtils.doSomething()
}
```

But if the pipeline calls a function defined as groovy script in "vars" directory, `gitUtils` is not visible anymore

```
def call() {
  def something = gitUtils.doSomething()
}
```

I also tryed to use @Field but it changes nothing. Note that all the pipeline is defined in the shared library (project jenkinsfile just calls a function from this shared library).

**How to access gitUtils from groovy scripts in /vars in this example ?**

I know we could pass the instance as parameter of function declared in /vars but more you have functions using you utilitary class, more it is ugly. Would you imagine to pass 'echo' or 'sh' function as parameter ? No, here is the same.

I know we could not use at all classes defined in src and define groovy script with multiple public methods. Here we could imagine create in /vars a gitutils.groovy with many public method. But this would imply to use 'script' closure in the pipeline to choose which method we want, like this:

```
script {
  gitutils.doSomething()
}
```

I dont want this. I would pref to create a single function per groovy script in /vars. Thus, we can call them directly in steps, like this:

```
 steps {
    myGroovyScriptFunction()
 }
```

But by doing such, the number of function increase and functions are not organized correctly. That is why the idea is to create "big step function" in /vars which use inside more generic functions, from instances of classes (even static in the better case). So, instead of creating a new instance in each groovy script, I would like a global instance.

Context: declarative pipeline, openshift jenkins, slave with dynamic pod template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because of [JENKINS-42360](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42360).

The best way to use global steps without a script block is in my opinion to define an instance of `GitUtils` and use it directly in the global steps. If you need the pipeline step context you can pass it to the constructor:

```
# vars/myStep.groovy

import my.packagename.GitUtils

def call() {
    GitUtils gitUtils = new GitUtils(steps) 
    ...
}
```

then you can use the steps with inside `GitUtils` as described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps). Remember to define `GitUtils` to implement `Serializable` as per documentation.

Comment: I can't use env since I am speaking about a class instance. Also, what you are saying about vars/ script is just not true and it is the exact puprose of this post : you can't access custom global groovy var.

Comment: And for the last point : you are right, we can define multiple public methods in groovy scripts but you cannot access them from a declarative pipeline unless you add a script closure which I do not want (when you define a single method with call() you can access it directly from 'steps' which prettier)

Comment: In the presented case (myVar is a string), my example works out of the box, since env variables are always strings. In the case of beans, you have the option to serialize and then deserialize your object. In all other cases, you have to rethink your pipeline structure and create the object directly in the global script. It's still unclear to me why you can't (or don't want to) use parameters for it.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. This behaviour makes no sense for me, we have to create the instance many time, we should be able to reach the global scope from function defined in /vars.

Comment: Also, I don't undertand the interest of giving "steps" as parameter since we can use the groovy feature wich allows us to declare the class with an access to the global scope, as described in the first example of the documentation link you gave. Maybe it is interesting to keep a "state" of specific steps, but seems to be a bad practice anyway. IMHO, the class should be full of static functions idealy, we can't do that just because we would lost the access to the global scope with static (sh, echo, ...). What do you think ?

Comment: I called it 'steps' like the official documentation does. Indeed 'context' would be a better wording for it. So you can access steps of the pipeline context in the class instance. Beside wording, the first example in the docs works only in the script context (scripted pipeline or script {} block). So you can define a util class with all static methods but you can use it only in the script context. It was a design decision in Jenkins to do this way. I don't say that I like it or that it's transparent to me.